# Installing DetectRTC package cause server internal error in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webrtc

I'm using [detectrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detectrtc)  in a next.js project. It worked perfectly fine till I added this package. After that HMR crashes. The error:

```js
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at new StyleSheet (/path/to/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/index/index.js:40:53)
    at new StyleSheetRegistry (/path/tonode_modules/styled-jsx/dist/index/index.js:306:37)
    at Object.createStyleRegistry (/path/to/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/index/index.js:445:12)
    at Object.renderToHTML (/path/to/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:284:46)
    at async doRender (/path/to/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:687:38)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.isManualRevalidate.isManualRevalidate (/path/to/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:796:28)
    at async /path/to/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:80:36
```

I've no clue how this could cause this error

I've tried the Dynamic import feature and checked the existence of window object but nothing changed